# How NgZone() is working in Microsoft Teams tab

Tags: angular, typescript, microsoft-teams

I am working on building the Microsoft Teams tab in Angular. As per the below code I am getting context from Microsoft. Where I am calling several functions, one of the function is `this.checkOwner()` which returns whether the person who is logged in is the owner or not.

So the issue which I am facing is, if am logged in as a member (not-owner) It sometimes returns the `true` and this is only coming If I am on a mobile app for the desktop app it's fine. Are there any delays caused by Ngzone?

```
microsoftTeams.getContext((Context: microsoftTeams.Context) => this.zone.run(() => {
   this.authSrvc.updateCurrentContext(Context);
   this.checkOwner();
   .
   .
   .
))}

checkOwner() {
   this.authSrvc.getOwnersList(this.authSrvc.currentContext.groupId).subscribe((res: any) => {
      const isExist = res.value.find(res => res.userPrincipalName === this.authSrvc.currentContext.userPrincipalName);
      this.isOwner = isExist ? true : false;
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We are not able to repro the issue at our end. Could you please check context.userTeamRole, If it return 0 user is the owner of the team and if return 1 user is member of the team. Please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/teams-js/userteamrole?view=msteams-client-js-latest) for more info